# Under what circumstances does "Community" vote to close as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, closing-questions

I proposed a possible duplicate for [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/158333/5930) and it received four close votes (including mine) with the fifth vote attributed to the Community user.

Under what circumstances does the Community user vote to close a possible duplicate?

(Purely a matter of curiosity on my part; obviously, I have no objection to the outcome.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can hover over Community's username in the vote to close listing to find out why it voted:

> This question's author approved a pending duplicate vote.

This happens because of [this feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250930/336144):

[image: Is your question a duplicate? dialogue]

When a question has close votes as a duplicate, the author is presented with a dialogue to either *edit* to clarify, or mark their question as a duplicate. By clicking "That solved my problem!", the Community user places a binding close vote and the question is marked a duplicate.

The Community user is shown rather than the author because:

- the author doesn't get a binding close vote on their question, so it wouldn't actually be closed
- the author might not even have close vote privileges (like shown here), so it wouldn't make much sense to show them as a close voter.

Comment: See also [this main meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250981/278659) where the announcement of this feature was made.

Comment: You know a lot for a linux penguin.

Comment: Huh.  Guess I don't ask enough questions, I've never seen that dialog.  Thanks!